# select 1 when there is a missing date - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to have a condition or return a result(1) when my query detects that I have a missing date and I'm calling it between two dates from the user.

As you can see I'm missing **3/22/2016 until 3/26/2016**. I want to get a result from my query that there are missing dates in my query.

Can you give me hints on how to do this?

Here's my query:

```
select DISTINCT DOB from DATES where STR_TO_DATE(DOB, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '20160301' AND '20160331'
```

[image]

Comment: You can use not exists clause to find your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give only date is missing or not.

```
select  case when count(DISTINCT DOB) = datediff('20160331','20160301') + 1 then 1 else 0 end 
from DATES 
where STR_TO_DATE(DOB, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '20160301' AND '20160331'
```

Below query will give you total dates present in it.

```
select asodate ,t1.dob 
from 
( SELECT @row := @row + interval 1 day as asofdate
FROM 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t,
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2, 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3, 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4, 
(SELECT @row:='2016-03-01' - interval 1 day) a
where @row < '2016-03-31') generateCalender
left join 
( select DISTINCT STR_TO_DATE(DOB, '%m/%d/%Y') as dob
from DATES 
where STR_TO_DATE(DOB, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '20160301' AND '20160331' ) t1
on asofdate = t1.dob
```

You can easily find out all missing date by adding where condition.

```
where t1.dob is NULL
```

Comment: THANKS that gave me exactly what I want :). I didnt know you have to use datediff when finding out the result ^_^

Comment: Its my pleasure to help you.